# TFS Build using vstest.console.exe.config instead of app.config

Tags: tfs, xunit

For some time we had TFS2017 run our unit test (xUnit) in the build proces. Every test project has it own `app.config` file declaring some appSettings.

Our code is looking at those app settings like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someSetting"]`

Recently, some developers upgraded from VS2015 to VS2017 (not sure if it is related), our test started to fail.

Turns out that the the appSettings where loaded from `vstest.console.exe.config`instead of the `app.config` file included in the test project.

While we where able to add our settings to `vstest.console.exe.config` this is not our preferred solution, we would like to have the test using the `app.config` file again.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I have no idea what changed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure WorkingFolder is not changed. It should be relative to the folder containing the test.dll.

Also, you can try the `<exec>` task in MSBuild to run the console runner.

When running multiple assemblies, you can specify the configuration file for each assembly using ItemGroup metadata. The `<xunit>` task looks for metadata named ConfigFile on each item in your item group. Configuration files are ignored when **AppDomains** is set to **false**.